# how to create jFuzzylogic project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

I did one project using fuzzylogic in matlab. since I am interested in java I would like to implement same project using java with help of jFuzzylogic library. I add the eclipse plugin but I don't know how to start and how to create file and where to write code. it will be better if someone step by step process to do the same above. can any help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]In order to create a new project in eclipse go to file then new and after that click on java project. After it a window will appear where you can give name to your project then click finish and after it right click on your project and then click new after it several options will be available and you can click on class in order to create a java class.

Comment: not this one sir, how to create flc files, incase if I create a class file for jFuzzylogic , how can I compile and run it, can u tel me sir.